# What's the best project type for a Task that needs to run daily in C#?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, visual-studio-2019, worker

I have a long processing task that needs to run daily, maybe using Windows Scheduler Task. 
In your opinion, what would be the best project type for a task that needs to be executed daily? 
I'm considering a Worker Service in .Net Core 3.2 but it seems to me that a Worker Service is more appropriate for monitor applications that runs constantly.

Comment: if you are on windows, use windows task scheduler and run your .exe at specified time.

Comment: other than that you can use hangfire/quartz.net/fluentscheduler or `IHostedService `

Comment: or just run your console app in a loop and check time (your own, ghetto task scheduler)

Comment: Please note that opinion-based questions are off-topic on Stack Overflow. Perhaps you could rephrase your question with more details so that it is on-topic.

Answer (score 1):

Create a Console application.  When you configure it in Task Scheduler, make sure that you also enter its full path in "Start in".